# What is the difference between MySQL Server and MySQL Client

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

In Ubuntu I normally install both but what are the differences between the client and server for MySQL.

As a bonus, when a new statement mentions that it needs MySQL 5.x does it mean the client, the server or both.  For example this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html mentions that it need 5.7.x for it to support json_extract, does this mean the client, server or both need to be 5.7.x

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The mysql server package will install the mysql database server which you can interact with using a mysql client. You can use the mysql client to send commands to any mysql server; on a remote computer or your own.

The mysql server is used to persist the data and provide a query interface for it (SQL).
The mysql clients purpose is to allow you to use that query interface.

The client package also comes with utilities that allows you to easily backup/restore data and administer the server.

Answer (score 45):

MySql Client :

> The mysql-client package allows you to connect to a MySQL server. It
>   will give you the "mysql" command-line program.

MySql Server :

> The mysql-server package allows to run a MySQL server which can host
>   multiple databases and process queries on those databases.

MySQL :

> The "MySQL" package probably includes both of the above.

If you just need to connect to a remote server and run queries, install just mysql-client. If you need to host a database, install the client and server.

Comment: Presumably, if I am using a server side language, like PHP or Coldfusion [.cfml] to query my databases, I only need to install MySQL Server. For instance, in Coldfusion, we use Coldfusion Administrator to set up our data sources, which uses a MySQL Driver to provide the connection. I also use Navicat for MySQL, which is a GUI for creating new databases etc.

Answer (score 16):

MYSQL operates in a networked environment using a client/server architecture.
A central program acts as a server and a various client programs connect to the server to make request.

MYSQL Server, or **mysqld** is the database server program.It manages access to the actual databases on disk or in the memory.

MYSQL Client are programs for communicating with the server to manipulate the information in the databases that the server manages. Example : **mysql** is the command line program that acts as a text-based front end for the server.