# AWS, ec2 and RDS mysqli::real_connect(): Connection timed out

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, lamp

1. I have set **Ec2 Linux server** with only **PHP is installed in it not mysql**.
2. I have separately configured RDS
3. Installed workbench and logged in using endpoint of RDS and username and password
4. **In workbench DB connection done**. I imported my local DB to RDS
5. Now In my Ec2 I onlu have PHP not mysql as my db is in RDS
6. In my ec2 php is running In check it with simple hello world echo file.
7. **But mysqli_connect script is giving connection time out error.** I used the same credentials as I used to connect to workbench. And I am also using the right script of mysqli_connect.
8. My doubt is Is it because of I did not installed mysql in my ec2 linux server. **But Why I need mysql in ec2 if I have successfully setup DB in RDS**.

Comment: You need to install mysql-client to allows you to connect to a MySQL server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962890/what-is-the-difference-between-mysql-server-and-mysql-client

Comment: You need mysql extension of PHP if you wish to use mysql... But maybe you do not have whitelisted IP address of EC2 to connect to RDS?

Comment: @Justinas I whitelisted IP address of RDS to EC2 for port number 3306.

Comment: @Shivani try adding `0.0.0.0/0` (public access) to your RDS inbound/outbound rules. Or even try logging in to EC2 via SSH and try connecting directly from mysql and not from PHP first

Comment: 8.My doubt is Is it because of I did not installed mysql in my ec2 linux server. But Why I need mysql in ec2 if I have successfully setup DB in RDS.                          ---->for this point. you need mysql client to connect to RDS mysql server. so install mysql client to access   rds from mysql. and make sure the port is open and is accessible publicly.

Comment: I did the following two things and it started working

1. sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
2. In RDS changed inbound and outbound to 0.0.0.0/0

Thanks all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that to install mysql-client and try that again. There can be several issues if it doesn't work even after trying to connect with mysql-client and consider those as well.

- The state of the RDS instance should be 'available'. Otherwise it won't connect to any.
- Check whether your EC2 instance IAM role has the permission which needs to access RDS instance. If your IAM role doesn't have permission then it won't get permission to connect and it will timeout after a while.

*It's better if you can post some code here.

Comment: I did the following two things and it started working

1. sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
2. In RDS changed inbound and outbound to 0.0.0.0/0

Thanks all for your support.